# How to know whether dataset/datatable contains CLOB data without reading any rows

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I have this reading datatable or dataset. If the data contains clob data, then file name has to changed.

But we first create the file and then come across the clob data. Is there anyway we can find the datatable contains clob data and then create the file.

Thanks,

Comment: Which filename are you talking about? Can you please precise your question? It looks like  a part of it is missing.

Comment: Application reads data from database tables and writes to csv.When database table contains clob data, file name has to be appended with "_clob". But problem is clob data is 3rd column hence when we read the 1st row 1st column we create a new file. Because if the data contains clob then file name should be appended with clob which we can't do as the file is already created and populated with data. Actually I am using OracleDataReader. Is there any way to know well before writing data to file that the data contains clob so that correct filename is used.

Comment: Can you just query the data dictionary, `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`, to check for any CLOB columns in the table before you start?

Comment: Alternatively, you could perhaps set a flag when you encounter a CLOB column, and conditionally rename the file after you're done writing it, if the flag is set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH to see if there is more than 0 bytes.